# Community Policy Repository

Tags: discussion, faq

This is the official repository for general community policy decisions.

### On Posts

- [How do we handle questions with answers on other sites?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/559/6)
- [Is the use of ChatGPT or other chatbot software forbidden?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/891/6)

---

### On Topics

#### Scope

- [Are astrophysics, cosmology, and theoretical astrophysics on topic?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/138/6)
- [Can I ask questions about the Earth?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/180/6)
- [Can I ask about UFOs?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/514/6)
- [Is astrology on topic?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/151/6)
- [What if astrology is only peripheral to my question?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/538/6)
- [Are resource requests allowed?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/206/6)
- [Are homework questions allowed?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/88/6)
- [Is history of astronomy on topic?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/364/6)
- [Are beginner questions allowed?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/442/6)
- [Is planetary science on topic?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8/6)
- [Can I ask about configuring astronomy software?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/300/6)
- [I want to share my personal theories here. Why can't I do that?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/436/6)
- [Can I ask for book recommendations?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/238/6)

#### Resources

- [Where can I find resources such as books to get additional information about astronomy?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/163/6)
- [Where can I share astronomy jokes?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/323/6)
- [I'm not a professional. Are there still ways I can help scientists online?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/192/6)
- [How does astronomy make a difference in the world?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/359/6)
- [Where can I find educational resources for astronomy?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/209/6)

---

### On Tags

#### Requests

- [Where do I request tags to be synonymized/merged or removed?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/67/6)

#### Usage

- [Should I tag my question based on concepts in the answers?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20/6)

---

### On Writing Guidelines

#### Grammar

- [What pronouns should I use for individuals?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/541/6)
- [Can I use emojis?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/516/6)
- [What are the rules for abbreviations?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/155/6)

#### Sources

- [Someone says I didn't properly attribute my source or I should have used quotes. Do I really have to do that?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/57/6)
- [What are the guidelines for linking to external materials or scripts I created?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/619/6)

#### Standards

- [Which temperature units should I use?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7/6)

---

### On the Blog

- [Where can I sign up to contribute to the community blog?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/470/6)

Comment: this is excellent!