# Should we at least temporarily ban chatbot-generated content (e.g. chatGPT) until it becomes clearer what it means for Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

Higher question-rate sites have already addressed chatbot-generated posting in an essentially universal negative way, for example:

- Stack Overflow: [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/3904031)

  - [How can we determine whether an answer used ChatGPT?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421880/3904031)
  - [Why was my answer deleted for using ChatGPT even when I didn't?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422066/3904031)
- Politics SE: [Use of ChatGPT to provide answers](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6454/16047) links to main meta:

  - [Could ChatGPT be a viable way to answer people's questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384355/could-chatgpt-be-a-viable-way-to-answer-peoples-questions)
  - [Ban ChatGPT network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384396/ban-chatgpt-network-wide)
- Math SE: [What is our policy on AI-generated content?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35342/284619)
- Help Center: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Recently a bit of ChatGTP was added to a question by the author AFTER the question was already answered by the same user. They properly cited the generating website and made it clear what was being done, but it seems almost gratuitous *ex post facto* chatbotting.

- [Can we simply multiply a positive value to each pixel in order to enhance contrast and to discard Time Delay Integration technique?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/51245/7982)

**Question:** While this is being sorted out in the greater Stack Exchange Ecosystem of communities and some guidelines and procedures are worked out, should we at least temporarily ban chatbot-generated content in Astronomy SE?

Comment: this was also posted in Space SE

Comment: Behind the scenes, we have already taken moderator action against a user for ChatGPT, but I support having a clear policy answer on it to avoid confusion.

Comment: See also: [Is there a list of ChatGPT discussions and policies for our sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384922/309993)

Answer (score 16):

**Yes.**

We should, at a minimum, temporarily ban chat generated content on Astronomy SE.  This content doesn't cite sources, generate mathjax, and it isn't the original work of those who might post it.  Even when quoted, chat generated content is not, as itself, an authoritative source, so it has no place on the SE.

Instead of having a separate specific policy against posting chat generated content, I propose we adopt the policy from the helpdesk linked by the OP above: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).